# Manage Cookie on Multiple "Domains"

Tags: php, javascript, apache, cookies

We have a local web server in our office that we use for some reporting and mundane order processing -- nothing major. I recently added some quick code to add a cookie to certain workstations so the user doesn't have log in all the time. The problem I am running in to is that since the server itself acts as an additional workstation, people can access it from http://127.0.0.1, http://localhost or http://192.168.1.111. This ends up creating three distinct cookie domains. Is there any way to configure the server to force one or the other? Or is my only option to move all bookmarks to point to the actual IP address and warn people not to use 127.0.0.1/localhost?

The server is running Apache 2.2 on Windows.

Comment: Why don’t you give that server a distinct domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and redirect the browser if a visitor hasn't gone in via the correct hostname.

```
if('servername' != $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    Location('http://servername/');
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a possible quick fix -- I think I can even move it to my .htaccess:`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^192.168.1.111$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.1.111/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: This seems like the best way to do it, IMO. The best URL to use is 192.168.1.111, so the code could be Location('http://192.168.1.1');

Answer (score 1):

If you're running an internal DNS server, you can configure a host/domain name for the server without having to register it - since it's for internal use only, you don't need to expose the name to the rest of the world.

Even without a DNS server, you can add an entry to each machine's hosts file to do the name->ip mapping.

Configure your site to use that name, tell everyone to use that instead, and then the cookies will take care of themselves, since they'll all be set using that host/domain name. You can then add vhosts for the IP-only hits and redirect them to the new named address.

Comment: I would love do something like that, but we don't have an internal DNS in place (our router is Cisco RV042 in case I'm wrong) and I don't want to have to manage the individual HOSTS file on every PC in our building. Additionally, we have mobile devices (namely iPhones and iPads) that <strike>need</strike> want access to the server too.Any ideas for a cheap internal DNS?

Comment: Got any windows/unix/linux servers? IIS has a DNS server and it's pretty easy to install Bind on unix boxes. Mostly it'd just be a matter of turn them on and pointing all the boxes at it for DNS lookups. Then you configure a domain/host for your web server and off you go.

Comment: Unix boxes don't need to be "servers" to run bind. Don't know if you could install the IIS DNS module on a non-server windows environment. But in either case, since that machine'd be your office's DNS server, you'd want to treat it like a server (backups, UPS power, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Typically cookies are set to domain names, not ip address. When using a domain name you can use a wildcard setting

```
.apple.com
```

Then any variation of that domain will accept the cookies.